# how to extract middle ten lines of a file using linux commands when total number of lines in the file is unknown?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

Suppose there is a text file with unknown number of lines and we need to extract ten lines in the middle of the file. 
How can we achieve the above using Linux commands?

Comment: check `wc`, `head` and `tail`.

Answer (score 1):

· wc : count lines (first result)

· awk : takes the lines returned by wc, divides by 2 and adds 5

· tail : gets the last -n lines

· head : gets the first -n lines

```
tail -n `wc filename  | awk '{print (int($1/2)+5) }' `  filename | head -n 10
```

This is aprox, doesn't work if you need check errors

Comment: the terminal showed "tail : filename : invalid number of lines "

Comment: "filename" is the name of the file you want to extract the 10 lines, you have to change both in the command.

Comment: i didn't mean filename as 'filename' either , but thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use wc to count number of lines

```
wc -l filename
```

Then, use Head and Tail to extract lines.
let's assume file has 50 lines.

```
head -n 30 filename | tail -n +21
```